# awk variables don't work for date grep

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

```
 cat log | awk '/^Jun 14 11:52/,/^Jun 14 11:56/'
```

This works, it gives me the lines of log between those two timestamps.

`cat log | awk -v start="$startTime" -v end="$endTime" '/^start/,/^end/`'

This does NOT work. It returns empty.

Is there something wrong in the way I've used the awk variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Between regex literals `/` and `/` you cannot use variables.

You can use:

```
awk -v start="$startTime" -v end="$endTime" '$0 ~ "^" start{p=1} p; $0 ~ "^" end{p=0}' log
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Is there documentation which explains this usage?

Comment: There won't be any documentation for this but in some online awk tutorials they would have shown similar examples.